# Continuously differentiable function injective on convex set

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis

Can you help me solve the following exercise:

> (a) Let $n\in \mathbb N$ and $G \subset \mathbb R^n$ a convex set, $f:G\to \mathbb R^n$ continuously differentiable with
>   $$det\left(\begin{matrix} \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_1}(c_1) \,\cdot\cdot\,\cdot \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x_n}(c_1) \\ .\quad.\quad.
> \\ .\quad.\quad. \\ \frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_1}(c_n) \,\cdot\cdot\,\cdot \frac{\partial f_n}{\partial x_n}(c_n)\end{matrix}\right) \neq 0 \quad \text{for all } c_1,c_2,...,c_n \in G,$$
>   Show that f is injective.
>   (b) We define $$g:(0,\infty)^2\to \mathbb R^2; \quad g(x) := \begin{pmatrix} x^2_1-x^2_2 \\ 2x_1x_2 \end{pmatrix}.$$
>   Investigate the injectivity of $g$ by applying (a).

Since the determinant is $\neq 0$ it is invertible on some nbhd of $c_n$. However, I don't know how to use that or the convexity property to show $f$ is injective.  If I know that, (b) should be trivial.

Comment: I edited it to make it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure I'm reading your notation correctly, but...

Suppose $f(a)=f(b)$ for $a,b\in G$.  Then let $h=b-a$, and $g(t)=a+t\cdot h$ for $t\in [0,1]$.  So $g'(t)=h$.  For each $f_i$, we have $f_i(g(1))-f_i(g(0))=0$ so by Rolle's theorem we have a $x_i\in [0,1]$ such that $(f_i\circ g)'(x_i)=0$. But $(f_i\circ g)'=\nabla f_i \cdot g'$, so $\nabla f_i (g(x_i))\cdot h = 0$.  Let $c_i =g(x_i)$.  But $\nabla f_i(c_i)$ are linearly independent by the assumption about the determinant above and there are $n$ of them, so they form a basis, and they're all perpendicular to $h$, which means $h=0$, which means $b=a$.

Comment: What is unclear about the notation?

Comment: @lappen68 You said that the determinant being non-zero means the map is invertible at $c_n$, but that matrix is not the Jacobian at $c_n$.  However, it is true that if $c_1=c_2=\ldots=c_n$ then it is the Jacobian, so yes it implies local invertibility.  You also had written it as a Jacobian in an earlier version, so I wasn't sure if that's what you meant.

Comment: It's not the Jacobian, that was indeed a mistake of mine. So your solution should be correct. Thanks! :)